# PowerShell: Avoid Conflicting "Prompt" function definitions

Tags: powershell, customization

PowerShell defines a default `prompt` function, and if you install something like [PoSh-Git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git), then it defines another. I myself have written a custom prompt that allows me to see when I have set a "Bookmark" for my current working directory location.

What I want to know is, what's the best practice for writing such a prompt, so that it doesn't conflict with others (i.e. what if my current working directory is has one of my bookmarks set *and* is a Git repository)?

Is there some way to capture the current definition and execute it at the beginning of my new prompt, so I get the output from both?

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Help About_Prompts` advises you can retrieve the scriptblock for the current prompt like so:

```
(Get-Command Prompt).ScriptBlock
```

Of course you can't do this from within the function lest you create an infinite loop so if you stick this in your profile or a module or something:

```
$promptscript = (Get-Command Prompt).ScriptBlock

Function Prompt
{
    Write-Output ("* " + (Invoke-Command -Script $promptscript))
}
```

You'll get an asterisk before whatever prompt is currently displaying, HOWEVER this relies on the ScriptBlock property of the existing Prompt function being available - if it is not (eg stuffed in a DLL) then you might be out of luck unless you can copy functions to another name (assuming it's even possible to do this in a DLL...)

Note: You will need to call the above AFTER everything else is loaded so it's probably worth either manually loading relevant module(s) in your profile then setting the prompt, or creating a function to load the module then set the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

So taking a look at how posh-git is implemented, one approach appears to be:

1. Make your custom prompt function a `Write-` function, using `Write-Prompt` with and without newlines as necessary.
2. Take the [posh-git example prompt](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/blob/master/profile.example.ps1) and make it your global prompt (or make you own) that simply calls the posh-git prompt (`Write-VcsStatus`) and then your own custom function, before returning "> ".

In short, don't have more than one profile function, simply write your bespoke prompt data using `Write-Host` in a function that can be called from one global `prompt` override.